# Phonegap: create new folder returns success but doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am currently creating an application using phonegap build and want to create a folder on my Android's root dir. For some reason, it returns a success message but the folder isn't visible! There should be a folder called "test-app" in my root, right? I want to load images and other files into this folder so that the user is able to open it later even without my app.

(called on device ready)

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, app.onRequestFileSystemSuccess, null);
```

(and inside the app object)

```
onRequestFileSystemSuccess:function(fileSystem) { 
        var entry=fileSystem.root;
        window.fileSystemRoot = fileSystem.root.toURL();
        entry.getDirectory("test-app", {create: true, exclusive: false}, app.onGetDirectorySuccess, app.onGetDirectoryFail);
    },

    onGetDirectorySuccess:function(dir) { 
    },

    onGetDirectoryFail:function(error) { 
    },
```

The important parts of my config.xml:

```
<preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>


    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" />

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-push-notification" source="npm" />

    <gap:plugin name='org.crosswalk.engine' version='1.3.0' source='pgb' />
```

So when I create an alert("works") inside the onGetDIrectorySuccess function, it alerts exactly this message. But for some reason, the folder isn't visible to me (tried to use the file manager and plugged it in my pc - nothing shows the folder). Where is my mistake?

Comment: which plugin version are you using? the latest doesn't write on the root folder, it writes on the app folder (something like data/data/com.yourapp.package/yourfolder)

Comment: Oh man - I used some old documentation but the new plugin. Thanks!